# Can I play with a controller?

Tags: golf-with-your-friends

Can I play this game with a controller? For example a xbox 360 or steam controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by the developer, controller functionalities are not yet implemented.

> "Not currently, we will be adding support for this in the future, it will include 360 and steam controller support."

He has however stated that it's not out of the equation and we will (hopefully) see it being implemented in a future update.

> "Unsure of an ETA at this point.
>   Currently this is a rough list of what order we will be adding it.
>   - Bug fixes and fixing the issues with the current updates.
>   - New level
>   - Video Options
>   - Gameplay Options (Controller)"

Source: [Steam - Controller support?](http://steamcommunity.com/app/431240/discussions/0/368542844481362848/)

Comment: Can you back this up with any sources? Your word isn't quite enough, at least not for me,

Comment: See [Controller Support](http://steamcommunity.com/app/431240/discussions/0/368542844481362848/)

Comment: Okay that's great but you might want to put the information in your answer. If that steam link dies, then there's no proof to back up your claims. If you put the information here, there's a solid backup of the info.